# PagedListHolder<clazz> cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As you know in spring mvc we can provide pagination mechanism using PagedListHolder class.
I already did provide methods that provide pagination for me but I got forced to do declare methods for all of my pages because I don't know how to pass generic type inside my methods

here is what I have done:

```
public class Jobs {
private PagedListHolder<Jobs> jobsPagedList = null;
private JobInfo[]jobs = null;
....
@RequestMapping(value = "jobs/getLatestJobs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String provideLatestTweet(HttpServletRequest request){
  ... checking tasks
  jobs = getLatestJobs();
  int firstElement = pagingHandlerForLatestJobs(request);
}
```

then here is pagingHandlerForLatestJobs() implementation :

```
private int pagingHandlerForLatestJobs(HttpServletRequest request){
  jobsPagedList = new PagedListHolder<JobInfo>(Arrays.asList(jobs));
//========================================================================//  
//How to pass above <JobInfo> classType as a parameter inside my method ? // 
//========================================================================//

 // ... setting some setting & returning the first page
}
```

I tried below method signature in order to accomplish the target:

```
private int pagingHandlerForLatestJobs(HttpServletRequest request, Class clazz)
```

and try to pass argument like this:

```
int firstElement = pagingHandlerForLatestJobs(request, JobInfo.class)
```

however when I was passing class inside:

```
new PagedListHolder<clazz>(Arrays.asList(jobs));
```

I encountered a runtime error:

> PagedListHolder cannot be resolved to a type

1) what problem my code has & why I can't pass that JobInfo inside ?

2) Can I solve this problem using Java Reflection API ? (if yes how ?)

Answer (score 0):

About your problem, no need to use reflection, plain generics will be enough. Here's what you can do:

Declare `jobsPagedList`  with a different type:

```
private PagedListHolder<?> jobsPagedList = null;
```

And the method as:

```
private <T> int pagingHandlerForLatestJobs(HttpServletRequest request) {
    jobsPagedList = new PagedListHolder<T>(Arrays.asList(jobs));

    /* ... do your magic */
}
```

**Note:** If you want to limit `PagedListHolder` to receive only `Jobs` and subtypes of it, change the declaration to `<? extends Jobs>` and the method to `<T extends Jobs>`.

Comment: So, did you try this one? It will work with `jobs` being an array of `JobInfo` or `EmployeeInfo` for sure.

Comment: why did you delete your last post ??? As I mentioned in the last post this will lead casting to List & casting to List will lead @SuppressWarning so this is not going to solve any problem ! but thanx dude !

Comment: No, **this will not require** any `@SupressWarning`. Try it out! Don't forget to change both the declaration of `jobsPagedList` to `<?>` and the method `<T> int pagingHandlerForLatestJobs()`, though!